# How to get started with Python SCTP stack (pysctp)?

Tags: python, linux, sctp

I've just installed pysctp from http://www.epx.com.br/pysctp/, and I'm having trouble getting the basic example working.  What could I be doing wrong?

I'm on Red Hat Linux.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 25 2011, 10:11:43)
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> import sctp
>>> sk = sctp.sctpsocket_tcp(socket.AF_INET)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sctp.py", line 1644, in __init__
    sctpsocket.__init__(self, family, TCP_STYLE, sk)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sctp.py", line 1016, in __init__
    self.events = event_subscribe(self)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sctp.py", line 623, in __init__
    self.__dict__.update(self.container._get_events())
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sctp.py", line 1356, in _get_events
    return _sctp.get_events(self._sk.fileno())
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone broke the ABI (added a few more fields to struct sctp_event_subscribe and the kernel wants userspace to want the new amount). Here's a kludge, proper fix would be for the kernel to accept old apps that have been compiled against headers with a smaller struct_event_subscribe  and just not give them the new fields...). Or even updating to the new-style header in lksctp-devel and recompiling everything.

```
--- _sctp.c~    2011-12-20 16:48:45.000000000 +0200
+++ _sctp.c 2011-12-20 16:49:23.498912252 +0200
@@ -832,8 +832,9 @@
 {
    PyObject* ret = 0;
    int fd;
+   char padding[4]; // Happily overflowing here...
    struct sctp_event_subscribe v;
-   socklen_t lv = sizeof(v);
+   socklen_t lv = 10; // Come to think of it, it could have been 9 at some point

    if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &fd)) {
        if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SCTP, SCTP_EVENTS, &v, &lv)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug internal to `pysctp`.  `get_events` calls `getsockopt`.

`getsockopt(2)` says:

> ```
>    EINVAL    optlen invalid in setsockopt().
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Brian's right - there's some sort of issue calling `getsockopt` for SCTP_EVENTS.  I've not been able to solve that, but I've commented out this line in sctp.py:

```
self.__dict__.update(self.container._get_events())
```

The SCTP sockets then seem to work fine.  I've not yet needed to get the SCTP_EVENTS, so this is fine for now.